# CORS issue with angular https request

Tags: angular, cors

I'm trying to access the API from an angular application. When I access the API with `http` protocol it works fine. When using `https` the below error is thrown.

[image: angular https error]

```
 get(url, params) {
    // this.http: HttpClient
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + this.constructUrl(url), { params: params }).pipe(res => {
        return res;
    });
}
```

[image]

When I debug, the URL passing to the httpClient is correct. Somewhere something goes wrong. Is there any setting required or Am I missing something?

> UPDATED: The issue with the interceptor (HTTPInterceptor -> setHeaders). I'm updating the headers. There it went wrong.

Comment: Can you please share your Angular code where you are doing the request?

Comment: `undefinedhttps://` suggests that `this.baseUrl` is `undefined` (and `this.constructUrl(url)` starts with `https://`).

Comment: What is the value of `this.baseUrl`?

Comment: As @mbojko suggested, `this.baseUrl` might be `undefined`. Also if your `this.constructUrl(url)` returns a fully defined URL like `https://...`, you do not need to append it with `this.baseUrl`. So try removing `this.baseUrl`.

Comment: Updated the question with debug mode screenshot

Comment: Strange. Do you get this error every time?

Comment: After switch to https from http